# Rest webservice in Java - Remove row from database

Tags: java, web-services, restful-url

i am trying to build a simple webservice with the usual CRUD methods connected to a database.
So far i managed to list all the "clients" from my table through the URL (receive a JSON string), but im not being able to remove or retrieve a row by passing a "id" parameter and i dont know why because i dont receive any error.

My work has 5 classes:

1. ClienteDAO
2. Cliente
3. Controller
4. ConnectionFactory
5. ClienteResource

**Cliente.java**

The class variables with SET,GET, hashCode and equal methods.

**ClienteResource.java**

```
@GET
@Path("/remove/{id}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String removeId(@PathParam ("id") int id) {
    return new Controller().removerCliente(id);
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public String removerCliente (int id) {
    return ClienteDAO.getInstance().removerCliente(id);
}
```

**ClienteDAO.java**

```
public class ClienteDAO extends ConnectionFactory {

...
    public String removerCliente (int id) {

    Connection conexao = null;
    PreparedStatement psmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    conexao = criarConexao();
    String query = "Delete * from cliente where id = ?";

    try {
        psmt = conexao.prepareStatement(query);
        psmt.setInt(1, id);
        psmt.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    } //finally {
        //fecharConexao(conexao, psmt, rs);
    //}

    return "O clientecom o id:"+ id +" foi apagado com sucesso!";
    }
  }
}
```

Can you identify something wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in your debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use * in your query:

```
String query = "Delete from cliente where id = ?";
```

[SQL delete statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Delete * from cliente where id = ?
Are you sure this query is correct?

Comment: No it wasn´t! :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not go and try: [Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) ?